# Ajax Post doesnt work the first time but it works the second

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I already asked this once, but now I cant fixed it the same way. I have a smartwizard page and when I click finish I want to call a php function throught ajax and get the response from the server.

So what happens is that when I click it the first time, the response is the full html code of my page, and it doesnt performs my function but it redirects to the other page. 
But when I go back to the  this page again and click it again, now it gives the response I want and it executes the function.

Does anyone have any ideas about why this happens?

Ajax Function:

```
if(confirm('Adicionar ao Carrinho?')){
    $.ajax({
        async:false,
        url:'booking/add_to_cart',

        success:function(response){
            alert(response);
        }, 
        error: function() {
            console.log($.makeArray(arguments));
        },
        complete: function() {
            console.log($.makeArray(arguments));
        }
    });
}else{
    return false;
}
```

My php controller function:

```
public function add_to_Cart(){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_data'])){
        echo "Tem de fazer login para adicionar ao carrinho";
        exit();
    }

    $detalhes_viagem=serialize($_SESSION['detalhes_viagem']);
    $idcliente=$_SESSION['user_data']['idcliente'];

    if(isset($_SESSION['hotel'])){
        $preco_hotel=$_SESSION['hotel']['preco_total'];     
        $hotel=serialize($_SESSION['hotel']);
        unset($_SESSION['hotel']);
    }else{
        $preco_hotel=0;
        $hotel="FALSE";
    }

    $voo="FALSE";

    if(isset($_SESSION['rent'])){
        $preco_rent=$_SESSION['rent']['preco_total'];       
        $rent=serialize($_SESSION['rent']);
        unset($_SESSION['rent']);
    }else{
        $preco_rent=0;
        $rent="FALSE";
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['trans'])){
        $preco_trans=$_SESSION['trans']['preco_total'];     
        $trans=serialize($_SESSION['trans']);
        unset($_SESSION['trans']);
    }else{
        $preco_trans=0;
        $trans="FALSE";
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['extras'])){
        $preco_extras=$_SESSION['extras']['preco_total'];       
        $extras=serialize($_SESSION['extras']);
        unset($_SESSION['extras']);
    }else{
        $preco_extras=0;
        $extras="FALSE";
    }

    $preco_total=$preco_hotel+$preco_rent+$preco_trans+$preco_extras;
    $this->model->add_to_cart($hotel,$voo,$rent,$trans,$extras,$preco_total,$idcliente,$detalhes_viagem);

    echo "something";
    exit();
}
```

My model function just inserts into the db these values

What happens is that when I first enter the page after setting the session it requires, this doesn't works although ajax executes success function. When I enter the page again it alredy works 100%.

Comment: Post your code, or a jsfiddle, or $$

Comment: where is your code..?

Comment: ~can't help without looking at your code!

Comment: Its like if when the session "detalhes_viagem" is first set it doesnt work but after it does...

Comment: What is happening in the first time...any error..?

Comment: No, no error, nothing.. the ajax fires, go to the function and the response i get is my whole html page code.. I can put the print and exit at the begginning of the function that it just the same.. when i leave the page and enter again it just works 100%.. so it has to be the ajax call..

Comment: Now i know what the problem really is.. The finish button.. Anyone that used smartwizard knows why finish button doesnt work the first time but the second does

Answer (score 0):

try this using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){


if(confirm('Adicionar ao Carrinho?')){
    $.ajax({
        async:false,
        url:'booking/add_to_cart',

        success:function(response){
            alert(response);
        }, 
        error: function() {
            console.log($.makeArray(arguments));
        },
        complete: function() {
            console.log($.makeArray(arguments));
        }
    });
}else{
    return false;
}
});
```